# Using an @Environment(\.managedObjectContext)—NSManagedObjectContext—in an init function

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I have this view.

```
struct AView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @State var timestamp: Date
    @State private var obj: MyObject
    
    init(date: Date)
    {
        // this is fine
        _timestamp = State(initialValue: date)
        // this gives an error
        _obj = State(initialValue: MyObject(context: viewContext))
    }

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
}
```

I need to initialize the object `obj`, which must be initialized with an `NSManagedObjectContext`, inside of the init function. However, when I try to use the code above, I get this error

> Variable 'self.obj' used before being initialized

How do I initalize a variable in the init function that depends on an `NSManagedObjectContext`?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63224046/12299030?

Comment: If `MyObject` is a Core Data entity, you shouldn't be using it with `@State` in the first place. That property wrapper doesn't work so well with reference types, which `NSManagedObject`, being a class, is.

Comment: Ya, I ended up taking in the object not as a state variable. @PatrickWynne is correct in this